# Upcasts in COM automatic?

Tags: c++, inheritance, com, interface

In COM, if I have an interface IBase and an interface IX which inherits from IBase, can I call methods of IBase through an IX pointer, and if not, why can I call Release() and AddRef() on any COM interface pointer without an upcast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can call whatever method of the base through the pointer to the derived. That's exactly why you can call `AddRef()`, `Release()` and `QueryInterface()` through any interface pointer.

Comment: Cool... thanks.  I hoped that was the case.  I'm pretty new to COM, though I've been aware of its basics for a while, but I'm rewriting somebody's DirectShow code and they use QI for exactly that case all over the place, so it got me worried!

Comment: They could confuse the upcast with the downcast. Downcast requires a QI() call (and a check to see if it succeeded).